# How to remove value have less than 5 frequency in value counts in python

Tags: python, pandas

i have a huge data and when and there a lot of duplicate so i wanna remove all value have less then 5 in value_counts() function

[image]

like this and less i wanna remove it

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If want remove values from counts `Series` use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
y = pd.Series(['a'] * 5 + ['b'] * 2 + ['c'] * 3 + ['d'] * 7)

s = y.value_counts()
out = s[s > 4]
print (out)
d    7
a    5
dtype: int64
```

If want remove values from original Series use [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
y1 = y[y.isin(out.index)]
print (y1)
0     a
1     a
2     a
3     a
4     a
10    d
11    d
12    d
13    d
14    d
15    d
16    d
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you mr.jezrael your answer so helpful and i will add a small tip, after you gathering the values this how you can replace the values :

```
s = y.value_counts()
x = s[s>5]
for z in y:
    if z not in x:
        y = y.replace([z],'Other')
    else:
        continue
```